# How to deserialize json object into flatten format direct field?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following structure:

```
public class User {
    private Account account;
    //constuctors, getters and setters
}

public class Account {
    private String id;
    private String description;
    //constructor, getters and setters
}
```

When I performing the request I need to create the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "account": 
    { 
        "id": "1",
        "description": "Some description"
    }
}
```

But I want to specify this information in a short way and ignore(left 'null') the 'description' field in the following way:

```
{
     "account": "1" // I want to set directly the id field in the account object.
}
```

How may I do it? I tried `@JsonCreator` annotation and `@JsonUnwrapped` but without result.

Comment: You can write a custom serializer for `Account` and use it on the field using @JsonSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used **@JsonCreator** annotation and created two constructors:

```
@JsonCreator
public Account(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("description") String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
}

@JsonCreator
public Account(String id) {
     this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom deserializer

```
public class AccountFromIdDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Account> {
  public AccountFromIdDeserializer() { this(null);}
  protected AccountFromIdDeserializer(Class<Account> type) { super(type);}

  @Override
  public Account deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setId(parser.getValueAsString());
    return account;
  }
}
```

And use on `account` node of `User` using `@JsonDeserialize`

```
   public class User {
      @JsonDeserialize(using = AccountFromIdDeserializer.class)
      private Account account;
      //constuctors, getters and setters
   }
```

Comment: Does it possible in this case use both way of specifing Json (short and normal)?

Comment: `both way of specifing Json` did you mean you want to serialize and deserialize both ?

Comment: No, I meant whether I can specify the JSON request in both way, in short and in normal way

Comment: Sorry, maybe you want deserialization, okay means can send id or full account object  right ?

Comment: Yes, that is true=)

Comment: @badCoder Here is a example for that https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization#on-mapper you need to  `mapper.readValue(json, Account.class);` when you found `{` as first character but it's very custom logic and bad design I think.